# Is there any way to use ffmpeg to download the video url and sync the video and audio without encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

I downloaded a video URL with audio, but the duration of the video and the duration of the audio are different and I want to match them.

I want to use the shortest option, but I can only do that by extracting the audio separately and taking two inputs, audio and video.

Is there an easy way?

1. used apad option